# Graph path at Haskell

Tags: haskell

Providing a list that replicates a list of edges of a graph, I want to make a function at Haskell that it returns true if there is a path from node A to B. My function seems to work in most of cases but it sometimes never ends. I know that I must keep a list with visited nodes but I am new to Haskell and I dont know how to achieve this because of the recursion. Can you help me?

```
-- the successor of a node, ex for the edge (1,2) the succ of 1 is 2  
suc x [] = 0  
suc x (l:list) =   
        if(x==(fst l)) then snd l  
        else suc x list


path 0 y list = False 
path x y (mu:m)  
    | x==y = True  
    | otherwise =   
        if ((path (suc x (mu:m)) y (mu:m))==False) then path (suc x m) y m  
        else True
```

for example: `path 1 6 [(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(5,4),(4,6)]`
nevers ends

I was thinking that I could just reverse the nodes , so that the left node is always the smaller one , but I believe it's a silly implementation.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the definition of `way`?  Can you provide type signatures for your functions as well?

Comment: Does every node have out-degree one? Because generally a node has multiple successors

Comment: @bheklilr my bad... I was testing cases and made the wrong copy. I will edit the post. I don't know how to formalize type signatures. Isn't the example good enough in order to understand my function ? :/

Comment: @NiklasB. No they don't. But seems the edges come in tuples I dont think that's a problem

Comment: @JmRag: If your edge list is `[(1,2), (1,3)]`, your algorithm will *never* go from 1 to 3, because `suc 1 = 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your edge list describes a general directed graph. The first problem is that your `suc` function returns only one possible successor, although in general there will be multiple. We can fix that by returning a list of successors instead:

```
suc :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> [Int]
suc x [] = []
suc x ((y,z):list) =
    if x == y then z : suc x list
    else suc x list
```

Or a bit shorter: `suc x = map snd . filter ((==x) . fst)`

Now the second problem is that you want to implement a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFS), but you didn't get it quite right: As you noted correctly, you are not allowed to visit nodes that you already visited. So you have to carry a list of already visited nodes through the recursion:

```
path :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [(Int,Int)] -> Bool
path src dst visited edges
    | src == dst = True
    | src `elem` visited = False
    | otherwise = any (\nxt -> path nxt dst (src : visited) edges) (suc src edges)
```

Example:

```
*Main> path 1 6 [] [(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(5,4),(4,6)]
False
*Main> path 1 3 [] [(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(5,4),(4,6)]
True
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. Now I see what I was doing wrong. Your functions works fine but since I am new to Haskell can you give me a brief explanation how the segment of otherwise works?

Comment: @JmRag: For every successor `nxt`, evaluate `path nxt (src : visited) edges` (that is, add src to the visited list and recurse). If any of those calls evaluates to True, we return True as well. If all of them return False, we return False.

Comment: Thx again a lot for your quick response and explanation!